# Toggle datatable row based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

This is my HTML..

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" id="datatable_ajax" style=" padding: 15px;" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable_ajax_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column descending">Date</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time">Time</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Transaction ID: activate to sort column ascending">Transaction ID</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Step">Step</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Step Type">Step Type</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="User ID: activate to sort column ascending">User ID</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="User: activate to sort column ascending">User</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type: activate to sort column ascending">Type</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Side">Side</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Coin: activate to sort column ascending">Coin</th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable_ajax" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Wallet: activate to sort column ascending">Wallet</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Price">Price</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Quantity">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Fee">Fee</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Fee USD">Fee USD</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Vendor Value">Vendor Value</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Vendor Fee">Vendor Fee</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Vendor Fee %">Vendor Fee %</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Vendor Fee USD">Vendor Fee USD</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Fee Castle X">Fee Castle X</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Fee Castle X %">Fee Castle X %</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Fee Castle X USD">Fee Castle X USD</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Net Qty">Net Qty</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Value USD">Value USD</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Net Value USD">Net Value USD</th>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="filter">
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm datetimepicker" name="time_from" placeholder="Starting Time">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm datetimepicker" name="time_to" placeholder="Ending Time">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="id">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="user_id">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="name">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="type">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="coin">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="wallet">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>09:23:56</td>
            <td>100000100</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100001</td>
            <td>Najam Masood</td>
            <td>MANUAL_DEPOSIT</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>1.00000000</td>
            <td>25.00000000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.00000000</td>
            <td>4.00</td>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>24.00000000</td>
            <td>25.00</td>
            <td>24.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>09:53:43</td>
            <td>100000101</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100001</td>
            <td>Najam Masood</td>
            <td>MARKET</td>
            <td>BUY</td>
            <td>ADA</td>
            <td>USDT</td>
            <td>0.02991</td>
            <td>534.8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3.25097967</td>
            <td>0.00243789</td>
            <td>0.074989</td>
            <td>0.01198198</td>
            <td>2.67400000 ADA</td>
            <td>0.5</td>
            <td>0.07997934</td>
            <td>532.126</td>
            <td>15.995868</td>
            <td>15.91588866</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>09:54:47</td>
            <td>100000102</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100001</td>
            <td>Najam Masood</td>
            <td>MARKET</td>
            <td>SELL</td>
            <td>ADA</td>
            <td>USDT</td>
            <td>0.02989</td>
            <td>532.1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3.23878225</td>
            <td>0.00243238</td>
            <td>0.075101</td>
            <td>0.01195174</td>
            <td>0.07952234 USDT</td>
            <td>0.5</td>
            <td>0.07952234</td>
            <td>532.1</td>
            <td>15.904469</td>
            <td>15.82494666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>09:55:47</td>
            <td>100000103</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100001</td>
            <td>Najam Masood</td>
            <td>MARKET</td>
            <td>BUY</td>
            <td>BTC</td>
            <td>USDT</td>
            <td>3405.15</td>
            <td>0.0047</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3.24967157</td>
            <td>0.00243725</td>
            <td>0.074999</td>
            <td>0.01199151</td>
            <td>0.00002350 BTC</td>
            <td>0.5</td>
            <td>0.08002102</td>
            <td>0.0046765</td>
            <td>16.004205</td>
            <td>15.92418398</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>09:56:57</td>
            <td>100000104</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100001</td>
            <td>Najam Masood</td>
            <td>MARKET</td>
            <td>SELL</td>
            <td>BTC</td>
            <td>USDT</td>
            <td>3404.19</td>
            <td>0.004676</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3.23718402</td>
            <td>0.00242676</td>
            <td>0.074965</td>
            <td>0.01190811</td>
            <td>0.07958996 USDT</td>
            <td>0.5</td>
            <td>0.07958996</td>
            <td>0.004676</td>
            <td>15.91799244</td>
            <td>15.83840248</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>10:32:05</td>
            <td>100000105</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100013</td>
            <td>Salim Shah</td>
            <td>DEPOSIT</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>1.27529060</td>
            <td>39.21</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.34</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.7088894</td>
            <td>1.9605</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>2.50</td>
            <td>37.24950000</td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>47.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>10:32:18</td>
            <td>100000106</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100013</td>
            <td>Salim Shah</td>
            <td>DEPOSIT</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>1.27529060</td>
            <td>45.48</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.52</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.93844171</td>
            <td>2.274</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>2.90</td>
            <td>43.20600000</td>
            <td>58.00</td>
            <td>55.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>10:32:35</td>
            <td>100000107</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100013</td>
            <td>Salim Shah</td>
            <td>DEPOSIT</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>1.27529060</td>
            <td>31.37</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.11</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.41557256</td>
            <td>1.5685</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>2.00</td>
            <td>29.80150000</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>38.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>10:36:16</td>
            <td>100000108</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100013</td>
            <td>Salim Shah</td>
            <td>DEPOSIT</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>1.27529060</td>
            <td>39.21</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.34</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.7088894</td>
            <td>1.9605</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>2.50</td>
            <td>37.24950000</td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>47.50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1">12-12-2018</td>
            <td>10:36:30</td>
            <td>100000109</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100013</td>
            <td>Salim Shah</td>
            <td>DEPOSIT</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>1.27529060</td>
            <td>31.37</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.11</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1.41557256</td>
            <td>1.5685</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td>2.00</td>
            <td>29.80150000</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>38.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a checkbox and I want to toggle the row based on 4th column `Step`. Basically what I want is that if that column has Checkbox is ticked, it should show those rows who has innerHTML of Step, and if it is unchecked, we will hide those rows whose innerHTML is either 1 or 2.

I am unable to loop through all the tr and td. We will ignore 1st row because it has not the data. So far I have tried this

```
$('#datatable_ajax tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        console.log($(this));
    })
})
```

But I can't seem to extract the innerHTML from this. Any help?

Comment: I cant see any checkbox in the HTML!!!

Comment: I haven't added it. I just need the logic to get it. That's working fine for me.

Comment: We do need to see a full exemple, what you have tried, it's code, and then we can try and resolve it for you.

Comment: But isn't this trying to find each td inside td elements that it finds in the first jQuery selector? How about you log also the elements in before $(this).find('td') ?

Comment: Somehow that is returning me 11 tds and that's all I need but I need to filter all except first one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get the value of 4th column in every record of the table

```
var i = 0;
$('#datatable_ajax tr').each(function(){
    if(i != 0)
    {
        console.log($(this).find('td:eq(3)').html());
    }
    i++;
})
```

Assuming that you want to get the value of each column in every record of the table

```
var i = 0;
$('#datatable_ajax tr').each(function(){
    if(i != 0)
    {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
    }
    i++;
})
```

**Note:**

1. Here i != 0 is used to skip the first tr(which contains headers)
2. in jquery index will start from '0' so if you want the 4th td you need to use index 3